error[E0277]: clone trait bound not satisfied
I am trying to implement HashMap. Basic defn is:
pub struct CLHashMap<K, V> {
    buckets: Vec<Vec<(K, V)>>,
    count: usize
}

For resize function, I have this:
let newSize = ....
let newBuckets = vec![Vec::new(); newSize]; // error here
for mut items in self.buckets.drain(..) {
      for (key, value) in items.drain(..) {
                let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
                key.hash(&mut hasher);
                let index = (hasher.finish() % newBuckets.len() as u64) as usize;
                newBuckets[index].push((key, value));
      }
}

mem::replace(&mut self.buckets, newBuckets);

This gives error at line annotated in code.
error[E0277]: the trait bound `K: Clone` is not satisfied in `(K, V)`

Error I understand, but I am not sure why rust needs clone trait to be implemented by V.
Is copying/cloning involved here?

rel: Initialize a large, fixed-size array with non-Copy types

You're thinking of it in terms of "Vec<T> is empty, so why can't it be cloned n times?".
Well, how does vec.clone() know that vec is empty? It doesn't. In short vec![item; n] simply creates a Vec<T> containing n (cloned) instances of item.
Since item is Vec<(K, V)>, then (K, V) must implement Clone, otherwise Vec<(K, V)> doesn't implement Clone.
There simply is no such thing as vec.clone_if_empty(), which doesn't really make sense.

Instead to create a Vec<Vec<T>> containing n empty Vec<T>s, you can use, e.g. iter::repeat_with(), take(n), and collect():
iter::repeat_with(Vec::new).take(n).collect()

or
(0..n).map(|_| Vec::new()).collect()

